# Update context from cookie data works on local but not on production

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm using Node js with an express server , HTTPS protocl. I have a problem in the production environment after the user performs a valid login  and close the browser it is not re logged in although the cookies are valid and remain in the browswer.

Ofc, when user perform valid login , i set cookie as follows:

```
res.cookie("userContext", tokenData, {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: false,
      path: "/",
      expires: new Date(someEpicTime),
      sameSite: "none",
    });
```

Now, in both local and production, the cookies are set in the browser with the correct data.

The problem is when I try to read the cookie when i re-open the browser and update my user context.

in localhost, it works perfectly and user remain logged in
in production, it is not logged in the user although the cookies exist with the correct format.

The FE URL is:`myDomain.net`
The BE API is:`api.myDomain.net:4000`